# How to compare todays date time with given date time, date time format is like date('d M Y - H:i A')

Tags: php

i want to compare current date & time with database date & time, the condition is

```
if($current_date > $given date) { 
    echo "deactive status"; 
}
```

main problem is date format is `date('d M Y - H:i a');` i want to compare this format only

Comment: Use `DateTime()` objects as they can handle any format (if you use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`) and they are comparable. But we won't give you code to do it as this question is too broad as you have not tried anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to create a datetime-object, which can be compared against other datetime objects. `$row['date']` is the database value.

```
$database_time = DateTime::createFromFormat("d M Y - H:i a", $row['date']);
$today = new DateTime();

if ($today > $database_time) {
    echo "Deactive status";
}
```

- [PHP.net on `DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)